# Get special values out of string (regex)

Tags: php, regex

Playing around with regex is a difficult thing for me.

I am trying to get the "values" **149** and **150** out of this string:

```
a:1:{s:7:"sliders";a:1:{s:10:"fullscreen";a:5:{s:6:"slides";a:2:{i:47;a:4:{s:9:"attach_id";s:3:"149";s:10:"slide_type";s:5:"image";s:5:"title";a:2:{s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:5:"color";s:0:"";}s:7:"caption";a:2:{s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:5:"color";s:0:"";}}i:48;a:4:{s:9:"attach_id";s:3:"150";s:10:"slide_type";s:5:"image";s:5:"title";a:2:{s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:5:"color";s:0:"";}s:7:"caption";a:2:{s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:5:"color";s:0:"";}}}s:9:"fit_style";s:7:"default";s:8:"controls";s:7:"default";s:6:"thumbs";s:3:"yes";s:8:"autoplay";s:7:"default";}}}
```

I tried this without any good results:

```
/^.*_id";s:3:"(.*)";.*$/
```

Comment: use a proper parser,..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using a regular expression, you need to add a '?` to your quantifier, so that you do not match the whole string in your group:

```
/^.*_id";s:3:"(.*?)";.*$/
```

This will, however, just map one value. To map all of them, use:

```
_id";s:3:"(.*?)";
```

Comment: Thank you! I did it that way!

Answer (score 2):

That is a serialized string, use unserialize

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 1):

You should use parser .With regular expression you can simply do

```
(?<=;s:3:")\d+
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vH0sZ0/2

```
$re = "/(?<=;s:3:\")\\d+/"; 
$str = "a:1:{s:7:\"sliders\";a:1:{s:10:\"fullscreen\";a:5:{s:6:\"slides\";a:2:{i:47;a:4:{s:9:\"attach_id\";s:3:\"149\";s:10:\"slide_type\";s:5:\"image\";s:5:\"title\";a:2:{s:5:\"value\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"color\";s:0:\"\";}s:7:\"caption\";a:2:{s:5:\"value\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"color\";s:0:\"\";}}i:48;a:4:{s:9:\"attach_id\";s:3:\"150\";s:10:\"slide_type\";s:5:\"image\";s:5:\"title\";a:2:{s:5:\"value\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"color\";s:0:\"\";}s:7:\"caption\";a:2:{s:5:\"value\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"color\";s:0:\"\";}}}s:9:\"fit_style\";s:7:\"default\";s:8:\"controls\";s:7:\"default\";s:6:\"thumbs\";s:3:\"yes\";s:8:\"autoplay\";s:7:\"default\";}}}"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$arr = unserialize($input);
foreach ($arr['sliders']['fullscreen']['slides'] as $a) { echo $a['attach_id']. "\n"; }
149
150
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a PHP serialized string, which can just be parsed out using the [unserialize function in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

However, if for some reason you really need to use a RegEx:

The RegEx that you're using is matching the first value, and then **the entire remainder of the string**. The `.*` is Greedy. Instead, you want it to be Lazy, so you can add a question mark after the `*` like this: `/^.*_id";s:3:"(.*?)";.*$/`

Secondly, because you're using anchors `^` and `$`, it will only match one occurrence. Either remove the anchors, or duplicate the pattern:

`/_id";s:3:"(.*?)";/`

`/^.*_id";s:3:"(.*?)";.*_id";s:3:"(.*?)";.*$/`

You can learn more about Lazy vs Greedy here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

My recommendation would be to use a defined match instead of the `.*`:

`/_id";s:3:"(\d*)";/`

As long as it will be a number, this will make your expression more specific and clearer for other people to read.

This is a good playground for testing RegEx expressions: http://www.regexr.com/3b74b